# Centering a SwitchCombat in a LinearLayout (gravity does not seem to work)

Tags: android, switch-statement

am struggling to center a switchcombat in a Layout.

I will attach a Code and a screenshot for you to get an idea.

The line: layout_gravity ="center" does not seem to work.

```html
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@drawable/x_linearlayoutcontainer"
                >

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/switchHeros1"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
                    app:showText="false"

                    android:checked="false"


                    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am still bothering about this. Does somebody else maybe have an idea?

Here the screenshot of the Design:
[Switch not Centered even though gravity is on center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Gvz.png)

Comment: Set the width to `wrap_content` and set `android:gravity="center"` on the LinearLayout`.

Comment: @TheWanderer okay, I checked your suggestion and this does not help. It sets the Container of the Switch to the right Side of the layout, obviously not fixing the issue. setting the layout in center with layout_gravity="center" does not help aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap your `SwitchCompat` with a `FrameLayout`. This is a known bug. Hope it help!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switchHeros1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:checked="false" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Heyhey. Thanks for your help.
I tried that and edited your post with a screenshot which shows that this did not solve the issue. It moved the switch to the left side of the view. :)

I think if you accept the edit, everyone can see the screenshot aswell.

Comment: Hey, this did not work for me and this still annoys me. Do you maybe have another idea how to try it?